# How to invoke JavaScript functions from an external .js file in JavaScript WITHOUT HTML?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using iMacros in combination with JavaScript in Firefox. The required scripts are stored on my harddrive. The scripts I am using are not embedded into a website. I am familiar with the procedure of how to make use of several JavaScript files in an HTML context but since I do not have that context in this case, is there some way I can continue?

Example:
script1.js

```
function Message(message) {
   alert(message);
}
```

script2.js

```
//Some reference to the file script1.js
var message = "Hello";
Message(message);
```

In that case I would want to run script2.js and have the alert pop up.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: when you say: without html, what do you mean?  In what environment will you be running this code?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a question for iMacros experts @dpdragnev, not JavaScript experts.

Comment: @dpdragnev I mean I am not building a website where I have a html part and a javascript part and, therefore, I cannot call js files from within the html code like  `<script src="script1.js"></script>` . I just have JavaScript to work with. I am starting the code through the iMacros browser extension (if that helps).

Comment: @mike You might be right. I am a beginner. Hence, I am missing the big picture. But there are probably other circumstances where this would be applicable. I am not sure.

Comment: @Christian Sure, I don't know anything about iMacros, so I'm afraid I can't help, or comment on applicability. Just wanted to warn the first commenter that it probably isn't what they were thinking it might be ;).

Comment: My bad, i did not read the question carefully.  I have never worked with iMacros so I am non sure i can be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to apply something like this:

```
// Some reference to the file script1.js
var extScript = imns.FIO.openNode("D:\\Temp\\script1.js");
extScript = imns.FIO.readTextFile(extScript);
eval.apply(window, [extScript]);

var message = "Hello";
Message(message);
```

Comment: This works and helps me out tremendously. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed something weird. If all functions are located in one `*.js` file and i run it in iMacros it's all good. But then, if I outsource the functions into an external file and refer to it like you suggested, some of the (outsourced) functions do not work properly, meaning they make different if then decisions. The IF THEN decisions do refer mostly to DOM elements in `window.document.*`, like for example, `if` an element is there `then` do this. Do you have an idea what causes this and maybe even how to avoid it?

Comment: Try to pass the window object in these functions directly as one of the parameters.